# how do I save a printed string from another function?

Tags: c

I want to test a function with type "void" which prints something.
Therefore I thought about using `sprintf` and saving the output of `printExample` in an array in the `testString` function.

my idea:

```
void printExample(){

   printf("This is a string");
}

void testString(){
   char stringArray[100];
   sprintf(stringArray,"%s",printExample());
   printf("%s",stringArray);
}

int main(){
   testString();
}
```

wanted output on console: This is a string

something seems to be wrong with the call of `printExample()` in my `sprintf`, any suggestions? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this questions shows lack of basic C++ (or C) knowledge. It is my suggestion to OP to read a good C++ book instead of try and error approach to C++ learning.

Comment: I cant change the return value "void" into anything else. Do you have any different solutions?

Comment: @SergeyA : the lack of understanding is perhaps why the question is unclear, but there is a useful question here perhaps regarding _how to capture a function's side-effect output for to unit-testing.  It is a legitimate aim, with an implausible suggestion.  I don't think many books (and in this case C rather then C++) will help with that.  Perhaps something un unit test frameworks?

Comment: @Harmie176  I advise always to leave out any "_my idea_" suggestions - expecially ones that demonstrably will not work.  What you will get in response is lots of explanation of why your suggestion won'r work, rather than a solution that will work.  There is a good question here despite the down-votes caused I suspect primarily by your naive and implausible suggestion. Omit that and just ask about capturing standard output for the purposed of unit testing.  Getting the right terminology and omitting unnecessary distraction is key to a good clear question.

Comment: @Clifford there is a certain wisdom in your words, I admit.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` output is known a *"side effect"* it is not returned by the function.

The somewhat complex solution in this case is to redirect `stdout` to a file, and then inspect the content of the file.

Something such as:

```
char* testString()
{
    // Redirect stdout to stdout.log
    int out = open("stdout.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0600);
    int save_out = dup(fileno(stdout));

    // Run function to be tested
    printExample() ;

    // restore stdout    
    fflush(stdout); close(out);
    dup2(save_out, fileno(stdout));
    close(save_out);

    // Read back captured output
    static char stdout_capture[100] ;
    memset( stdout_capture, 0, 100 ) ;
    FILE* fp = fopen( "stdout.log", "r" ) ;
    fread( stdout_capture, 1, sizeof(stdout_capture) - 1, fp ) ;
    fclose( fp ) ;

    // return captured text to caller  
    return stdout_capture ;

}

int main()
{
   printf( "%s\n", testString() ) ;
}
```

Note I have omitted any error checking code in the file I/O for clarity.  You might want to add some!

Answer (score 1):

Function `printf` writes to the console, but it has nothing to do with the return value of a function in which it is used.

So `void printExample()` will print `This is a string`, but it will - as the return type correctly indicates - not return anything that could be used by the caller of `printExample`.

Using `printExample` as is as parameter to an `sprintf(stringArray,"%s",printExample())` is undefined behaviour; `sprintf(...,"%s"` expects a `char*`-argument, but `printExample` is `void`. Your compiler should have warned you.

If you want `printExample` to return a string, you'd have to write

```
const char* printExample() {
   return "This is a string";
}
```

Then you can use the result of a call to `printExample` directly as argument to another `printf`.

If, however, you just want to capture everything that is printed to `stdout` also in a string (e.g. in order to do automated tests), then you could temporarily buffer  `stdout` and access this buffer then.

```
void printExample(){

    printf("This is a string");
}

void testString(){
    char string[100] = {0};
    setbuf(stdout, string);
    printExample();
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    printf("\noutput of printExample: '%s'\n",string);
}

int main() {
    testString();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you have changed the behaviour of the function he is trying to test - which is not the point of a test.  The function no longer prints _anything_.

Comment: @Clifford: right; probably did not get OPs intent.

Answer (score -1):

you should use return instead of print function,
then it will have an output as "This is a string".
Like in this photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZwYe.png)

Comment: Do not pose off-site images, and do not post imaged of _text_ that could easily be copy&pasted to your answer.

Comment: Please post code directly in your answer instead of linking to an image. You can read about why images of code and errors are discouraged [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: He is trying to test the _side-effect_ of a function - changing the function rather defeats the purpose.